# Send SMS using jSSC

Tags: java, jssc

I am sending `sms` using jSSC with AT commands. Below is my code

```
serialPort.writeBytes(("at+cmgf=1"+"\r\n").getBytes());

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            serialPort.writeBytes(("at+csca="+c+"+92300000042"+c+"\r\n").getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            serialPort.writeBytes(("at+cmgs="+c+"03327172883"+c+"\r\n").getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            serialPort.writeBytes(("hello"+control_z).getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
```

My problem is, if i remove `Thread.sleep` statements then sometimes i don't receive `sms` and sometimes if i receive, i receive at commands in sms text itself.

What is the proper way of doing it with at commands?

Comment: Usually AT command execution takes some time. I am not sure, if these commands can be executed back to back / asynchronously.

Comment: how can i synchronously execute these commands ?

Comment: implement CommandResponseHandler  interface. This article might help here https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/rel/3.4/core/da/html/device_access/atcmd.htm

Comment: I'm using java SE with jSSC